# My hamburger menu isn't responding on specific pages?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've created a hamburger menu using `HTML`, `CSS`, and `JavaScript`. The `:hover` seems to work just fine, and on certain pages the transition animation works fine too; however, I've recently added a tile system to a few pages (the only content on those pages aside from the global nav), and noticed that the `form` element was the primary focus when inspecting the `DOM`. I then changed the `z-index` for several classes in the `CSS` and that's when the menu stopped responding to the `JavaScript`. I'm not sure if that's the true cause, and I've tried unrolling the changes to see what in particular caused the issue, but I can't seem to track it down. Hence, I am here; I figure those more knowledgeable than myself can possibly spot an issue with the `CSS` that I'm not seeing.

---

After typing up this question and entering the snippet below, I can't seem to reproduce it here, and I've compared the code here, to the code on my webpage and everything seems identical. I'm truly at a loss on this one, after failing to reproduce here I began to think it was perhaps crossed styles between something perhaps cached by Edge, but after further inspection in the `DOM` this doesn't seem to be the case.

Feel free to visit [my website](http://perpetualjstudios.com/) where this problem is currently live and visit one of the three pages linked below (preferably on mobile, or resize the browser to simulate a smaller screen for the menu to appear).

- [Games](http://perpetualjstudios.com/Games/Landing.aspx)
- [Software](http://perpetualjstudios.com/Software/Landing.aspx)
- [Apps](http://perpetualjstudios.com/Apps/Landing.aspx)

For comparison to what should actually happen, feel free to visit the [home](http://perpetualjstudios.com/Default.aspx) page, or the [about me](http://perpetualjstudios.com/About.aspx) page; or simply run the code snippet below apparently.

---

The code snippet below is from the page where the menu doesn't respond to `JavaScript`.

```js
var wrapperMenu = document.querySelector('.hamburger-menu');

wrapperMenu.addEventListener('click', function () {
    wrapperMenu.classList.toggle('active');
    document.getElementById('globalnav').classList.toggle('active');
})
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700);

*, *::after, *::before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    background-color: #333;
    z-index: 3;
}

a.title {
    cursor: default;
    color: #eee !important;
    display: none;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    font-size: 25px;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    transition: 0.5s all;
}

nav a {
    text-decoration: none !important;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #eee;
    font-size: 25px;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    transition: 1s all;
    transition: 0.5s color;
}

    nav a.active {
        color: #3cf;
    }

    nav a:hover {
        color: #3cf;
    }

.main-content {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 50px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    z-index: 2;
}

.tiles {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: center;
    z-index: 2;
}

.tile {
    width: 200px;
    height: 180px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .05);
    transition: 0.1s;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    will-change: all;
}

    .tile p {
        padding-bottom: 0.3em;
    }

    .tile .title, .tile .amount, .tile .icon {
        color: #333;
    }

    .tile .title {
        font-size: 16px;
    }

    .tile .amount {
        font-size: 10px;
        font-weight: 200;
        opacity: 0.7;
    }

    .tile .icon {
        font-size: 40px;
        padding-bottom: 0.3em;
    }

    .tile:hover, .tile.initial {
        transform: scale(1.05) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        background-color: white;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
        border-radius: 3px;
        box-shadow: -13px 11px 25px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
        transition: 0.3s;
    }

        .tile:hover .icon, .tile.initial .icon, .tile:hover .title, .tile.initial .title, .tile:hover .amount, .tile.initial .amount {
            color: #3cf;
            opacity: 1;
        }

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    nav {
        position: fixed;
        top: 50px;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #555;
    }

        nav a {
            display: none;
        }

        nav.active a {
            display: block;
            padding-top: 5px;
            padding-bottom: 5px;
            transition: 1s all;
        }

        nav a:hover {
            box-shadow: 1920px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) inset;
            text-shadow: -2px 2px 15px;
        }

    a.title {
        display: block;
    }

    .hamburger-menu {
        position: fixed;
        top: 10px;
        right: 10px;
        z-index: 5;
        height: 30px;
        width: 30px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-between;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: 0.75s all;
    }

        .hamburger-menu.active {
            transform: rotate(-405deg);
            transition: 0.75s all;
        }

        .hamburger-menu div {
            background-color: #eee;
            border-radius: 5px;
            height: 2px;
            transition: 0.75s all;
        }

        .hamburger-menu:hover div {
            background-color: #fc3;
        }

        .hamburger-menu.active div {
            background-color: #f33;
        }

        .hamburger-menu div:nth-child(odd) {
            width: 15px;
            transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.54, -0.81, 0.57, 0.57);
        }

        .hamburger-menu div:nth-child(even) {
            width: 30px;
        }

        .hamburger-menu div:nth-child(1) {
            transform-origin: right;
        }

        .hamburger-menu div:nth-child(3) {
            align-self: flex-end;
            transform-origin: left;
        }

    .active div:nth-child(1) {
        transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(3px);
    }

    .active div:nth-child(3) {
        transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(-3px);
    }
}
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css">

<header>
            <a class="title">Perpetual J Studios</a>
            <nav id="globalnav">
                <a href="#" class="active">Home</a>
                <a href="#">About</a>
                <a href="#">Academy</a>
                <a href="#">Software</a>
                <a href="#">Apps</a>
                <a href="#">Games</a>
            </nav>
        </header>

        <div class="hamburger-menu">
            <div class="half"></div>
            <div></div>
            <div class="half"></div>
        </div>

        <!-- BODY -->
        <div class="main-content">
                <div class="container">
        <ul class="tiles">
            <li class="tile">
                <i class="fas fa-mobile icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <p class="title">Budget</p>
                <p class="amount">Example</p>
            </li>
            <li class="tile">
                <i class="fas fa-mobile icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <p class="title">OBD Reader</p>
                <p class="amount">Work in Progress</p>
            </li>
            <li class="tile">
                <i class="fas fa-mobile icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <p class="title">Vehicle Dashboard</p>
                <p class="amount">Work in Progress</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
        </div>
```

---

I forgot to mention that the `form` element now has an inline `z-index` of `-1` to ensure that all other content is rendered on top of it and is easily reachable via the `DOM` during debugging, I'll probably remove prior to final release.

Comment: Check your console - on all of the non-working pages you linked, your JavaScript files are linked incorrectly, and as such they are returning `404 NOT FOUND`. For example, your *Games* page is in the `/Games/` folder, so your JS references are looking in `/Games/Scripts/Navigation.js`, which is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you specified wrong path of js files for those 3 pages. Change the path to as`<script src="../Scripts/Navigation.js"></script>` they are inside the folder.

Comment: I knew it had to be something simple; I had reworked that with the nav but forgot to do it with linked files. Thanks for pointing that out.